# Jinja2 Group by Month/year

Tags: jinja2

I'm trying to group a list of date/times in Jinja by month/year. Here's the code I have right now:

```
{% for group in EventsList|groupby('date') %}
        <b>{{group.grouper}}</b><br />
        {% for event in group.list %}
            <i>{{event.title}}</i>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

But the problem is that it currently groups by a specific date. I'd like to group by Month/Year (i.e. January 2011, February 2011 etc..).

Would it be more efficient to do this in Python instead?

thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could first groupby('date.year') and then groupby('date.month').

```
{% for year, year_group in EventsList|groupby('date.year') %}
    {% for month, list in year_group|groupby('date.month') %}
        <b>{{ month }} {{ year }}</b><br />
        {% for event in list %}
            <i>{{event.title}}</i>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you! Just wondering, is it possible to format the {{month}} as long form (i.e. October) instead of a number (i.e. 10). I was also considering an alternative approach where i'd just create another column in the datastore for long form month/year (i.e. "October 2012") ...but that would be pretty inefficient.

Comment: You can use `{{ month.strftime('%B') }}`. See http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: I know this is old, but you most certainly cannot `month.strftime(...)` because month will be an integer.

Comment: but you can do `date.strftime(...)` which will work .)

Comment: What does the data object look like for this?

Comment: that nested groupby is sweet