# Filter or split a list in Jinja template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm working with Jinja templates in Flask on Python and trying to achieve the following.

I have a list of items ('trainings') that have a certain start date. I'm looping through them succesfully and got the order sorted on date. I'd love to add sub headers that divide the long list of trainings with sub headers, e.g. "this week", "next week", "later". How would you go about this? I was thinking either

- Add something in Jinja template that would look at the date and group by these dates
- Add a method in the python class for trainings that tells the template which grouping it belongs (e.g. "this week") to, but how do i then use that to sort and add the sub headers?

Many thanks!
Scott

```
    {% for training in trainings|sort(attribute="starts_at") %}
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{training.starts_at.strftime('%A, %d %b')}} - {{training.title}}</h5>

            <p class="card-text">Short description about the training</p>
            <a href="{{url_for('trainings.showSingleTraining', training_id=training.id) }}" class="btn btn-primary">See information</a>
                            
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <br />
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I found it, you can use groupby in Jinja, see below for an example. Could also use this more customized if I add a class method that returns custom grouping (for example: "this week", "next 4 weeks", "later")

```
{% for year, year_group in trainings|groupby('starts_at.year') %}
    {% for month, list in year_group|groupby('starts_at.month') %}
        <b>{{ month }} {{ year }}</b><br />
            {% for training in list %}

        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

source: [Jinja2 Group by Month/year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764291/jinja2-group-by-month-year)