# Jinja2 template: output format

Tags: python-3.x, templates, jinja2

i am quite new to jinja2 template and i try to get output data  by using jinja template.

data_list=

```
[
    {
        "v4-filter": {
            "accept_1": [
                {
                    "destination-prefix-list": "v4-future-prefix-list-1"
                },
                {
                    "source-prefix-list": "v4-future-prefix-list-2"
                },
                                {
                    "source-prefix-list": "v4-future-prefix-list-3"
                },
                {
                    "destination-port": "80"
                },
                {
                    "destination-port": "443"
                },
                {
                    "action": "accept"
                }
            ],
            "accept_2": [
                {
                    "destination-prefix-list": "v4-future-prefix-list4"
                },
                {
                    "source-prefix-list": "v4-future-prefix-list5"
                },
                {
                    "action": "accept"}]}}]
```

My jinja template

```
{%- for d  in data_list -%} 
    {%- for k,v  in d.items() -%} 
        {%- for term,value  in v.items() -%}
          term:: {{ term }} 
          {%- for dict_item in value -%}
            {%- for key, value in dict_item.items() -%}
               {% if  key == "source-prefix-list" %}
                 source-address:: {{value}} 
               {% endif %}
               {% if  key == "destination-prefix-list" %}
                 destination-address:: {{value}} 
               {% endif %}
               {% if  key == "destination-port" %}
                 destination-port:: {{value}} 
               {% endif %}
               {% if  key == "action" %}
                 action:: {{value}} 
               {% endif %}
            {%- endfor -%}
          {%- endfor -%}
        {%- endfor -%}
    {%- endfor -%} 
{%- endfor -%}
```

Output that i get

```
term:: accept_1
               
                 destination-address:: v4-future-prefix-list-1 
               
               
               
                 source-address:: v4-future-prefix-list-2 
               
               
               
               
                 source-address:: v4-future-prefix-list-3 
               
               
               
               
               
               
                 destination-port:: 80 
               
               
               
               
                 destination-port:: 443 
               
               
               
               
               
                 action:: accept 
               term:: accept_2
               
                 destination-address:: v4-future-prefix-list4 
               
               
               
                 source-address:: v4-future-prefix-list5 
               
               
               
               
               
               
               
                 action:: accept
```

Output that i want

```
term accept_1 {
    source-address:: v4-future-prefix-list-1
                     v4-future-prefix-list-2
                     v4-future-prefix-list-3
    destination-port:: 80
                       443
    action:: accept
}

term accept_2 {
    source-address:: v4-future-prefix-list-5
    destination-address:: v4-future-prefix-list-4
    action:: accept
}
```

The jinja template looks not nice i know, but at the end it contains all the information that i need, is just question now to format properly as expected.

I tried by using nested if statement to properly reach the result but with no success.

Any hint is welcome.
Thanks, Pablo.

Comment: Which part of output is a **problem** for you? E.g. removing ``::`` after the `term` shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I basically want to have the jinja template able to provide me that output like     source-address:: v4-future-prefix-list-1                                                                                                            .                                                        v4-future-prefix-list-2                                               .                                                        v4-future-prefix-list-3                             for example. see "Output that i want" in my original post

Comment: If your problem is output values in **groups** (`source-address`, `destination-port`), then use google e.g.for "jinjia group". See e.g. code in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764291/jinja2-group-by-month-year).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following template will produce the requested output:

```
{%- for d  in data_list -%}
{%- for k,v  in d.items() -%}
{%- for term,value  in v.items() -%}
{%- set label = namespace(source=false, dest=false, port=false) %}
term {{ term }} {
{%- for dict_item in value -%}
{%- for key, value in dict_item.items() -%}
    {%- if key == "source-prefix-list" %}
    {% if not label.source %}source-address::{% else %}{{ ' '*16 }}{% endif %} {{value}}
    {%- set label.source = true %}
    {%- endif %}
    {%- if key == "destination-prefix-list" %}
    {% if not label.dest %}destination-address::{% else %}{{ ' '*21 }}{% endif %} {{value}}
    {%- set label.dest = true %}
    {%- endif %}
    {%- if key == "destination-port" %}
    {% if not label.port %}destination-port::{% else %}{{ ' '*18 }}{% endif %} {{value}}
    {%- set label.port = true %}
    {%- endif %}
    {%- if key == "action" %}
    action:: {{value}}
    {%- endif %}
{%- endfor %}
{%- endfor %}
}
{% endfor %}
{%- endfor %}
{%- endfor %}
```

Output:

```
term accept_1 {
    destination-address:: v4-future-prefix-list-1
    source-address:: v4-future-prefix-list-2
                     v4-future-prefix-list-3
    destination-port:: 80
                       443
    action:: accept
}

term accept_2 {
    destination-address:: v4-future-prefix-list4
    source-address:: v4-future-prefix-list5
    action:: accept
}
```

Here we use a [Jinja2 namespace object](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#assignments) that we can use to track whether a label has been already printed or not in the current cycle. If a label is printed, we flip the boolean tracking variable in our `label` namespace variable and then just print enough space to correctly align the next printed value.